# Why won't dropwizard upload an xls file?

Tags: java, io, jersey, dropwizard

I've made a pretty conventional file upload method using dropwizard.

So I have a method in the resource that starts off like this

```
@POST
@Path("/uploadFile")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@UnitOfWork
public Response uploadFile(
    @FormDataParam("file") final InputStream fileInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("file") final FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader, 
    @Context HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {...
```

Nothing special inside, it just saves to a path, using java.nio libraries, like so

```
java.nio.file.Path outputPath = FileSystems.getDefault()
    .getPath(System.getProperty("user.home"), fileName);

    if (!Files.exists(outputPath.getParent()))
        Files.createDirectories(outputPath.getParent());

    Files.copy(fileInputStream, outputPath);
```

It just will not upload an excel file. I read elsewhere that excel files and their underlying type are viewed with suspicion. What do I need to do please?

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Are you getting some exceptions? "Won't upload" can mean any number of things. Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: @peeskillet - sorry for leaving the question in a bad state. The problem was down to a bad usage of nio.file (I think) for the actual output stream. I'll answer the question and show what I did.

Comment: A quick look at the repo shows that it was not the nio stuff, but bad usage of the Files.copy method. I went on holiday, and forgot all about this :-)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the method worked for other files, but would not upload a xls file. I don't know the exact reason, but my suspicions are posted in the question. The way I got it working was to replace the simple copy line

```
Files.copy(fileInputStream, outputPath);
```

with

```
OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputPath.toString()));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = fileInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        outputStream.close();
    }
```

Which gets around (what I suspect is a security feature) by reading the input stream into a byte array, and then writing it into a new FileOutputStream.

If anybody has a "proper way," that is better than this, it would be cool to see it. The stack trace didn't tell me much about what was going on.